# Ruby on rails timeout during large uploads

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to upload my files on aws s3 using ruby on rails. Code is working great for smaller upload but for uploads greater than 3-4mb, i get timeout error. I am uploading files on s3 using code:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(filename, params[:file].read, @BUCKET_NAME, :access => :private)
```

How can i resolve my issue for larger uploads. Can i increase the timeout interval time for ruby scripts for allowing larger uploads?

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using: aws-s3 gem

When you are **dealing with large files you have to use I/O stream, so that file is read in segments.**

Instead you might use something like this:

`S3Object.store('roots.mpeg', open('roots.mpeg'),  @BUCKET_NAME, :access => :private)`

More details can be found: http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this approach also even then, ruby script timeout error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking advantage of the recent CORS support. I tried to detail clearly how to use it there : http://pjambet.github.com/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [http streaming](http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming) for long request